# curl dans serveur ou script ne marche pas

Tags: php, file-get-contents

curl activer dans mon serveur et safe mode ( on )

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$fp = fopen("resource.txt", "r+");
fwrite($fp, $content);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Lorsque je veut importer Html de se site dans fichier text 
fichier toujours vide :/
file_get_content est bloque dans serveur

Comment: When I want to import HTML site in text file still empty file: / file_get_content is blocked in server

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English website. Please use an English title as well as English inside your question.

Comment: You aren't using `file_get_content`. Do you mean `resource.txt` is empty or `$content` is empty? Please update the question to an english version.

Comment: file_get_content is disable in serveur doesn't work for me . when run script nothing happend resource.txt is empty